# How do you kill yourself?

Tags: final-fantasy-4

I got to the top of Mount Ordeals and killed the boss. It was a long and drawn out battle, that I don't care to repeat. I figured there couldn't be more battles after the boss, so I ventured forward rather than backwards to heal and save.

Mistake.

Now I'm a paladin (or in the process of becoming a paladin) and I have to kill my former self (a dark knight). My attack only did a paltry 10 damage, so I want to be sure I know what I'm doing before I venture further into the fight and possibly lose.

How do you kill the dark knight in this boss fight? Am I doomed for having attacked the opponent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more a test of your new-found devotion to the side of good than it is a fight.

You've just got to skip a few turns by defending or using "Cover," and you'll eventually "win" by not fighting.

If you've attacked already, that's okay, but the fight won't end until you've chosen not to continue your aggressive behavior.